# Problem in connecting Oracle 11g through JDBC thin driver ( Domino Java )

Tags: java, jdbc, lotus-notes, oracle11g

I'm unable to connect Oracle 11 database remotely using following piece of code. However, same code works fine if I try to connect Oracle 9 database which is installed on my machine. What is missing ?

( I'm not getting any error, Lotus Notes hangs )

```
import lotus.domino.*;
import java.sql.*; 
import oracle.jdbc.*;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
public void NotesMain() {
            try {

        Session session = getSession();
        AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
        Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();

        //Calling connection method
        Connection conn= getOracleConnection(db);
        if(conn!=null){
               System.out.println("Connected..");
        }         
        else {
               System.out.println("There is a problem in connecting database..");
               System.exit(0);
        }        

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}  

 private static Connection getOracleConnection(Database db) throws Exception {
    // Register driver
 DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
    //Retrieving connection  string from profile document.
 String host = "SPRPRG020.int.server.com";
 String ip = "1521";
    String user = "system";
    String password = "password";
    String sid = "XE";
    String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+host+":"+ip+":"+sid;
   return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you step through the code in a debugger, do you, by chance happen to encounter the line whose execution hangs the thread?

Comment: @Vineet, Not able to do so, Code freezes Lotus Notes.

Comment: Also,I assume nothing wrong in using thin driver to connect remote Oracle database.I'm suspecting something syntactically wrong in my connection string.

Comment: Hang could be waiting for network response. Can you ping SPRPRG020.int.server.com ? If so, can you telnet to SPRPRG020.int.server.com on port 1521 ? Alternatively, can you connect through something like SQL*Plus in instant Client ?

Answer (score 2):

OK Guys, Now I'm able to connect.. Here are all possible connection string I've tried and all works,

```
1- "jdbc:oracle:thin:@server.cgg.com:1569:ServiceName"

2- "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server.cgg.com:1569/ServiceName"

3- "jdbc:oracle:thin:@server.cgg.com:1569/ServiceName"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, syntax for JDBC URL for oracle 11 g has changed

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/service_name" />
```